# Django - update query doesn't work in pre_delete signal

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, django-signals

I tried to update a `Transaction` model queryset in the below `pre_delete` signal that connected to the Wallet model, but it didn't work.

The signal triggers, and all lines work correctly, except the last line :(

```py
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Wallet)
def delete_wallet(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_default:
        raise ValidationError({"is_default": "You can't delete the default wallet"})

    q = {"company": instance.company} if instance.company else {"user": instance.user}

    try:
        default_wallet = Wallet.objects.get(**q, is_default=True)
    except Wallet.DoesNotExist:
        default_wallet = Wallet.objects.filter(**q).exclude(pk=instance.pk).first()

    if not default_wallet:
        raise ValidationError({"is_default": "You can't delete the last wallet"})

    instance.transactions.all().update(wallet=default_wallet)
```

Answer (score 1):

I moved the logic to the `delete()` function of the `Wallet` model instead of using the `pre_delete()` signal, and it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it cant find default wallet so it tries go get the first one which is the wallet you want to delete (because it's before delete so it still exist).

Try to exclude `pk=instance.pk` in your `default_wallet` query.

Comment: I tried this before, but it didn't work out.

Comment: But it's still required for correct logic. Please update your question with that `exclude`.

Comment: It's updated now.